# saving Textbox data to excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, textbox, save

I need help with saving user entered data (textbox) to an excel file. The excel file should be created on desktop automatically. I can add one textbox to excel but not multiple. If possible can you give code on being able to open the same file when btnopen is clicked, thank you!

my code right now for save button.

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

```
    SaveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv*)|*.csv"
    If SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
    Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText _
        (SaveFileDialog.FileName, txtBMI.Text, True)
    End If


    table.Rows.Add(DateTimePicker1.Text, txtBMI.Text, txtHeight.Text, txtWeight.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub
```

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/H73M8.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjtjw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a supported library of creating Excel file and not to do it with file.create as you did.
You can use Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library and add a refernce to the bin folder or other dll of working with Excel instance.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

You can see it here -
http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_create_file.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add first the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library via

Project>Properties>References>Add>COM>Type Libraries>Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

Add releaseObject function (To release the excel file in the app):

```
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

After adding, declare the necessary variables so that it's easier to control the excel file:

```
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim raXL As Excel.Range
    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' Add a new workbook.
    wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Add
    shXL = wbXl.ActiveSheet
    shXL.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
    shXL.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA3
    appXL.Visible = False
```

Add the headers with bold text:

```
    With shXL.Range("A1", "D1")
                .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    shXL.Cells(1,1) = "Date"
    shXL.Cells(1,2) = "Height"
    shXL.Cells(1,3) = "Weight"
    shXL.Cells(1,4) = "BMI"
    shXL.Cells(2,1) = DateTimePicker1.Text
    shXL.Cells(2,2) = txtHeight.Text
    shXL.Cells(2,3) = txtWeight.Text
    shXL.Cells(2,4) = txtBMI.Text
```

Next, open the excel file.

```
    appXL.Visible = True
    appXL.UserControl = True
    shXL.SaveAs("C:\Book1.xml")
    raXL = Nothing
    shXL = Nothing
    wbXl = Nothing
    appXL = Nothing
    releaseObject(shXL)
    releaseObject(wbXl)
    releaseObject(appXL)
```

Comment: Where do I put your 2nd, 3rd & 4th code in my program? sorry, I'm not too sure. After I open excel file, am I suppose to do anything in excel or what?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Delete everything on your Save button and replace it with the 2nd, 3rd and 4th.

Comment: After you open the excel, you decide whether to save it or don't.

Comment: Never mind, got it working. Instead of launching excel, how to automatically save it to desktop when save clicked? Do you know how to do that. btw I really appreciate your help

Comment: WbXL.SaveAs("path you want"). write that after the third part.

Comment: Sample: wbxl.SaveAs("C:\Book1.xml")

Comment: That breaks the program. :(

Comment: I edited my answer. Check the 4th part. Mark this as answered if I answered what you needed.

Comment: Try shXL.SaveAs("C:\Book1.xml").

Comment: unfortunately same thing :(
http://puu.sh/ogCVQ/889eb93d19.png
Just to let you know man, you don't know how thankful I'm. Thank you so much for helping man.

Comment: Which part of code makes Excel pop up when the button is clicked? maybe it would be work if excel didn't open and it just plotted the data into excel and saving/creating the file.

Comment: Try the shXL.SaveAs then Wbxl.Close after that.